# Laravel subtract automatically 2 hours from real data

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a problem with save date in my db with backend in **Laravel 5.1** and frontend **AngularJS 1.5.7**.

**If i send** date to my backend with Angular uib-datepicker, and if I send for ex. **11/05/2017 00:00:00** , in my db **Laravel** with `Model::create($data)` **saves 10/05/2017 22:00:00**, so I have to parse this date with Carbon like `Carbon::parse($data['expiration'])->timezone('Europe/Rome')`, but are there a ways to avoid this process?

**EDIT**

If I use only `Carbon::parse($data['expiration'])` without method `->timezone('Europe/Rome')` it save wrong date and I have in my `config/app.php` the correct timezone: `'timezone' => 'Europe/Rome'`

Comment: That's correct because it saves in UTC

Comment: Thankyou Alexandr, so I should always parse my date with carbon and set My timezone? because if I don't put ->timezone('') it save wrong date

Comment: Yes. Better to do so, to keep supported multi timezone

Comment: If you're only operating in one timezone, you can change the application timezone in your `config/app.php` file.

Comment: Thankyou fubar, my problem is that I HAVE in my `config/app.php` the correct timezone: `'timezone' => 'Europe/Rome'` I Have edited my post

Comment: Have you tried `Carbon::parse($data['expiration'])->tz('Europe/Rome')` ?